# This method must return a result of type GObject - but just look -- I told it to --

Tags: java

I would like to know what to think when I type out what should be a perfectly good method, but it doesn't get recognized as a method. Here it is.

```
private GObject getCollidingObject() {
    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX(),ball.getY());
    if (gobj != null) {
        return gobj;
    }
    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX()+BALL_RADIUS,ball.getY());
    if (gobj != null) {
        return gobj;
    }
    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX(),ball.getY()+BALL_RADIUS);
    if (gobj != null) {
        return gobj;
    }
    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX()+BALL_RADIUS,ball.getY()+BALL_RADIUS);
    if (gobj != null) {
        return gobj;
    }
}
```

Now eclipse is telling me that "This method must return a result of type GObject," and is  NOT highlighting the GObject in purple, which is its usual way of telling me that it is happy with my work.

What should I be thinking? I looked carefully over all my open-closed brackets and all my other methods are working, so I don't think I have it placed this method within the wrong scope...

At the bottom of my program with all my other instance variables, I had

```
private GObject gobj;
```

But that doesn't seem to be helping me out.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Your declaration of `private GObject gobj` as an instance variable is indeed helping you out, though not in a way you might like. Since you don't define `gobj` when you use it in your method, it automatically uses the instance variable `gobj` - if you didn't have this, it would complain that it doesn't know what `gobj` is. But this means you're returning an instance variable from a method that also modifies it, which you usually don't want to do.

Comment: *"... which is its usual way of telling me that it is happy with my work"* - It is unhealthy to attribute desires and emotions to your tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that your `gobj` is not declared as a `GObject`.  It doesn't matter what it actually is a an instance of, it needs to either be declared to be the return type (or one of its sublcasses/implemented classes or interfaces) or be successfully cast as such.

What is `gobj` declared as?

EDIT:
And of course, you need to ensure that there is a return statement for in EVERY case.
You do not have a default that would be hit if all of your `if` statements evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Note that code in comments isn't worth the hassle; please edit your original question...

Comment: aha - fixing the conditions to see if that solves things... It did! It did! So the lesson is, if your method doesn't have all its conditions in order, it won't be recognized as a method at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems with your function; first, you don't declare `gobj` within the method body. You made a comment elsewhere that makes me think that you're trying to `return` a data member of the class; that's odd design, to say the least. (Normally, the goal is to have each method stand on its own as much as possible. If you're sharing data like this, you risk introducing bugs that are difficult to find later.)

Your function does not *always* return data -- sometimes it'll just fall off the end of the function without an explicit `return` statement. *You* might know that one of those four conditions will always be true, but the compiler does not -- and honestly, it'll be correct as you'll inevitably break that condition in the future.

This code is difficult to write in a way that makes it more beautiful. (Well, if Java's [`||` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) worked with `null` as well, this could be a very beautiful short function. But Java's `||` only works with `true` and `false`.)

Probably the easiest way to re-write the function is to remove the guard after the last attempt:

```
private GObject getCollidingObject() {
    GObject gobj;

    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX(),ball.getY());
    if (gobj != null) {
        return gobj;
    }
    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX()+BALL_RADIUS,ball.getY());
    if (gobj != null) {
        return gobj;
    }
    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX(),ball.getY()+BALL_RADIUS);
    if (gobj != null) {
        return gobj;
    }
    gobj = getElementAt(ball.getX()+BALL_RADIUS,ball.getY()+BALL_RADIUS);

    return gobj;
}
```

This way, you'll execute at least one `return` no matter which path you take through the function.